# Python: MultiThreading , Web Service. Is there a way to create a new thread for every request that i get on a python web service?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-services

I want to create web service which accepts data on a port, generally processing this data would take around 2 mins. In mean time if I get another request on the port, I want to create another thread to process the new request.

I am not returning back any result to the requestor.

Any library or example to help me do this?

Please Help.

Comment: If your project is big and complex task, you can use https://github.com/richardhenry/hotqueue, otherwise you can take a look into this https://github.com/richardhenry/hotqueue

Comment: Thanks, I will check this project out.

Answer (score 0):

first note that any regular webserver like apache will start a new process upon every request so if for example you're going to use django to expose that webservice, in production environment django will be running behind apache.

to release the client making the webservice call you'd probably have a queue that accumulates requests and workers that consume those requests and process them, for such architecture check out [celery task queue](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: I dont want to have a queue, rather let me reframe, as soon i get the request, i want to send a confirmation to the client stating "Req Ack", due to which the client wont wait for a reply from server. 
Basically client is passing some data and the processing of data is taking 20 mins. I dont want client to wait for confirmation even if the request fails.

Comment: well, it depends how that http server call will be accepted, the thread that return ack to the user is no longer yours, in other words you have to either use queue or start a new thread / process for that, using a queue is a much better option for many reasons

Comment: On apache you can control this behaviour with mod_wsgi using the WSGIProcessGroup directive. That way you can prevent new processes being started between requests: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIProcessGroup

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be just what you are looking for:

[Ladon task types](https://pythonhosted.org/ladon/tasks.html)